# How and where we add XML sitemap on WooCommerce website?

Tags: xml, woocommerce, sitemap

How and where we add XML sitemap on WooCommerce website? as i am adding it on root but i can not getting the url  www.xyz.com/sitemap.xml
I am getting this url by adding www.xyz.com/xmlsitemap.php

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which type of content to include in the sitemap, such as posts and pages, as well as WooCommerce products, and any other post types that are in use.

[Kwayy HTML Sitemap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnwl4.png)

Once you have selected the what you want to display in your html sitemap, you can add the follow shortcode to a new page in WordPress:

[kwayy-sitemap]

This is probably best suited to sites with under ~1000 products. Any more than that, and you would probably want to split out your sitemap into paginated pages or categories.